# Postgres select rows that have a percentage match, and sort by percentage

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of sentences in a postgres database. The table is called `sentences` and the column that stores the sentence for each row is called `sentence`.

How can I compare the sentences to a given sentence and return the ones in which, say, 60% of the words (or even better the roots of the words) match and then sort the results by the quality of the match?

Ideally a 90% match would come before 70% match and a 50% match wouldn't show at all.

Ideally it would exclude punctuation as well, but that's not a necessity.

Comment: I would do it in some real programming language, not SQL.  This kind of task makes for long and unreadable SQL queries.

Comment: @IlyaKogan I need to query a postgresql database though and I don't want to download the entire table every time I query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [fuzzystrmatch](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/fuzzystrmatch.html) module, especially the `levenshtein` function. This calculates the "distance" between two strings, with lower values meaning they are more similar. It's generally used  between two words, but as long as the sentences aren't too long (max string length for each argument is 255 bytes), you could use them with  sentences as well.

Then you would sort by the output of the `levenshtein` function ascending, with the results going from most to least similar.

If you wanted to exclude punctuation, call `regexp_replace` on the strings with a regex to remove all characters you would like, replacing it with empty string, and use those return values as the arguments to `levenshtein`.

Comment: Works pretty well! Thanks.